# How to use module as text?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that contains modules, now I would like to use the string value of the module (see example). Is this possible or am I better of just creating a second dictionary?

```py
import module1
import module2
import module3

module_dict = {
    'module1': module1
    'module2': module2
}

user_input = input()
module_dict[user_input].function()

#module3.function requires two strings to work, one of the string happens to be the name of the module
module3.function('foo', module_dict[user_input])
```

This is a really simplified version, forgive me if it looks confusing. I can not use the built-in `str` function since it will result in `module 'modulename' at 'path'`, which is not what I am after.

Comment: You already have the module name in `user_input` don't you? `module3.function('foo', user_input)`

Comment: Sadly not the input is different from the module name. The actual project is a flask app and the info comes from a selection in a form. The options are different from the module names
EDIT: I also can't change the names of the modules since the form inputs contain '.' which conflicts in python

Comment: How about `module_dict[user_input].__name__` then?

Comment: Not fully what I am after but now I can slice it to get the correct string. Thank you very much for the quick solution!

Comment: Why are you so afraid of running your code that you want to ask here before trying?

Comment: Excuse me? I just wasn't aware of the existence of ```__name```? I think sometimes people forget that others often have to learn things

Comment: Oh sorry, I read that wrong. It was just a typo because this is a quick example and nothing like the real code. I would love to see you write everything perfectly first try though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a module's name from its `__name__` attribute:

```
import itertools

print(itertools.__name__)
```

Outputs

```
itertools
```